# Track who downloaded a PDF from my Custom Facebook Tab

Tags: facebook, download, facebook-page

I am going to create a custom page tab on Facebook and offer a free downloadable PDF with information about my services. Is it possible to track which Facebook users have downloaded the PDF?

Answer (score 3):

An option to look into is authenticating the users individually and receiving their respective Facebook user IDs as a result. You may be interested in reading up on the page tab authentication process referenced here:

**Reference**: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/pagetab/

Once you have this user ID, you can track their activity by opening a session containing their user information (to identify them when they download the PDF). For instance, assuming you're using PHP (alongside a CMS):

```
<?php
    if ($current_user->fb_id == 0) {
        exit();
    } else {
        echo $current_user->fb_id;
        // do stuff with user here
    }
    header("Location: http://www.example.com/file.pdf");
    // redirect them to the actual file
?>
```

Hopefully this pseudocode gives you a starting point on your project.